# Nanosecond interrupt accuracy on a 64MHz microprocessor

Tags: microcontroller, timer, interrupts, clock-speed

I am currently designing a PCB with a 64MHz nRF52832 bluetooth MCU. I have an interrupt connected to this MCU which needs to be detected with 1-3 nanosecond accuracy.

Unfortunately, the 64MHz MCU has a clock cycle of 15.625ns, meaning the interrupt could be recognized up to 15.625ns late (assuming zero interrupt latency for now). Please note that the interrupt does not need to be acted upon straight away, I only need to know at which time it arrived.

Is there any way for me to use external circuitry to improve my accuracy? I've considered using an external nanosecond timer to measure the offset, and sending that to the MCU every time the interrupt is triggered. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time finding any timers that can run at this speed.

I am capable of changing the MCU to a faster processor, however nothing greater than ~180MHz - which would still be 5.56ns per clock cycle. For this reason, a creative external solution would be ideal.

Comment: You should probably consider using a FPGA with a fast clock.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am limited on size and budget - I am hoping there is an alternative solution, before deciding to use an FPGA.

Comment: 1ns accuracy compared to what reference? Is this a situation for a time-to-digital converter? What's the source of the signal and its rise time?

Comment: +1 for time-to-digital converter, but it won't be cheap. Knowing more about the actual problem to solve would help.

Comment: My apologies, by 'accuracy' above, I believe I meant precision. As long as the ns measurement is consistent, it does not have to be synched to any specific reference.

This interrupt is coming from a DWM1000 module - an ultra-wide-band module used for indoor locating. This module is controlled by our nRF52 MCU. 

The flow is as follows:
1) DWM1000 sends interrupt
2) MCU commands DWM1000 to respond at delay = [ns offset + clock_cycles*15.625ns later]
3) The above calulcated delay value is used in further calculations.

This delay value needs to be precise for our calculations.

Comment: FPGA definitely. But not just fpga, it would require something else. Not sure how they actually do it, i would measue signal phase against FPGA clock.

Comment: [Here's a tdc](http://www.acam.de/products/time-to-digital-converters/tdc-gp1/) with 250 ps resolution, looks inexpensive.

Comment: @tomnexus Just as a note to you and the OP: resolution \$\ne\$ accuracy.

Comment: Hmm. I have never worked at these speeds. But have you considered a current source feeding a capacitor, reseting the capacitor on every 64 MHz clock edge, and using a sampler for the analog voltage on the capacitor when the event arrives to freeze the value for later reading with an ADC? Something like a few tens of mA into a 220nF cap? Maybe all I'm doing is sweeping the problems around, though.

Comment: @jonk of course, but skim the datasheet, it's not bad, and there are others with 40 ps resolution. For accurate timing OP will need a low jitter reference clock, definitely not the microprocessor's built in clock.

Comment: @tomnexus I had missed some of the comments because of the way that this site "trims" out commentary unless I force it. The OP had written that there was no need for accuracy. Just low cost. By the way, the datasheet linked to the page you mention gives me an ERROR rather than the datasheet.

Comment: TDC-GP1 - not recommended for new design

Comment: I can't help thinking that the cumulative errors and inaccuracies in other parts of your system, such as PCB tracking and connector capacitance to name only two, will outweigh the benefits of the 1..3 ns part of it.

Comment: and even if you did find a much faster mcu, there is no reason to assume the peripherals run that fast, they dont need to match the cpu speed, so some are speed limited to a fraction of the system/cpu speed.  Read the datasheets to find out more (assuming you could change parts).

Comment: Some PICs provide Time-Voltage measurement peripherals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Theoretical considerations

For a digitizing system to detect something with a temporal resolution of \$\Delta t\$, it needs to have a sample rate of at least \$\frac2{\Delta t}\$. That's a corollary of Nyquist's sampling theorem.

In your case, this means that whatever pin might cause an interrupt that somehow notes the time the signal edge happened, you'd need some sampling clock (or, more precisely related to your application: a counter that can be latched on the external signal) running at least at 666.67 MHz.

## practical considerations

Nothing short of that will do, unless you can build an external system that somehow converts the event into something slower that can then be observed afterwards to calculate the time it happened.

So, what I'd propose is actually the approach you've been recommended in the comments, namely, using high-speed counter e.g. inside an FPGA to capture the time and read it whenever you're ready with your MCU.

Or, you use the impulse and very fast analog electronics to e.g. kick of e.g. an exponential voltage decay which you can periodically observe and extrapolate from the observed rate of decay the point in time when it got started. That way, you'd actually be trading ADC resolution (interrupt pin: "1 bit ADC", if you want so) for timing resolution. You'd still need a pretty good ADC and accompanying CPU speed.

In the end, your problem is a hard one, as detecting nanosecond precision pulses is a *hard* problem – even starting from a PCB layout point of view (the quality of your pulse edge is a function of the signal bandwidth you can transport on your PCB trace – and for a signal with 1/(1ns) = 1 GHz fundamental frequency, this already becomes non-trivial).

You'll probably either need a very fast FPGA, or aforementioned analog time-to-function converter, a moderately fast ADC and a moderately fast FPGA to deal with the ADC data.

## scratch that.

I just read up on time-to-digital converters. Maxim (e.g. MAX35102) and TI offer such (other company certainly, too).

As far as I read this, there's different approaches, but the TI TDC7200, for example, uses an internal ring oscillator (which runs at pretty high speeds, giving you high resolution) to run a counter.

The ring oscillator is disciplined against an external clock, so you'll have to make sure your accuracy needs are met by the quality of that clock.

Comment: I would personally try abusing an FPGA deserializer. It is possible to get relatively low end FPGAs that have serializers capable of >1Gbps, which should provide at least 1 ns resolution. It may be necessary to do some external calibration to get the absolute delay nailed down, though.

Comment: Thank you to you and everyone who recommended a TDC! It took some researching to find one with a short enough measurement range, but fortunately TI makes the [TDC7201](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7201.pdf) which goes down to 0.25ns and is similar to what you suggested. I think I'll give this a go!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to generate high accuracy timing with a variety of tricks; the
action of an MCU on interrupt, however, is unlikely to be of such precision.

One option is to start an oscillator, and beat it against a reference
oscillator  [vernier time measurement](https://www.google.com/patents/US4164648) .  This requires an oscillator
that can be started in a known phase (usually, a delay line and inverting
gate), and a time reference, with a phase detector.   The phase detector
gives a fine-adjust correction to apply to the coarse timing afforded by
conventional counter timing.

The vernier timer requires a long time, so a modest clock (20 MHz) can
proceed for a hundred-count while the phase measurement is being completed.
It can thus take several microseconds to complete a 1 ns time determination.